# Xamarin Android WebView Automatically restart on Rotation

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android, screen-rotation

I am facing an issue on Xamarin Android WebView control, when I rotate my device, it automatically restart the app and get me to the url that i load onCreate. 
i have used `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in  android menifest file, but issue not resolved. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding this line, this issue is resolved.

```
    [Activity(Label = "Test App", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/TestLogo", ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```